# How to use getters in PHP?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. My previous experience is in Java.

I have the following problem:

I have class `product`, where I have private variables and public getters. I also have a file index, where I have created object `Product`. I pass `Product` to a function in class `DB` using `do_something($product)`. In `DB` I have this:

```
public function ($product) {
    echo $product->getParam;
}
```

> Problem: Notice:  Undefined property: product::$getParam

How to fix it?

Comment: show the code of the class, as well as the code where you create an instance of product, and try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in Java, when accessing a method of an object, one includes parentheses.

Instead of:

```
public function someMethod($product) {
   echo $product->getParam;
}
```

Use:

```
public function someMethod($product) {
   echo $product->getParam();
}
```

Even better would be to follow [psr2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) and write it like this:

```
public function someMethod($product)
{
   echo $product->getParam();
}
```

And still better would be to include the expected class type as a type hint:

```
public function someMethod(Product $product)
{
   echo $product->getParam();
}
```

When you don't put the parentheses, you're accessing a property instead. If the property existed under the name `getParam` (and was public), that would have worked as well.

Answer (score -1):

First there is a function name missing, I use `myFunction` below.
Then you should check if product is an object:

```
public function myFunction ($product){
    if (is_object($product)) {
        ...
    } else {
        # catch the error / fault
    }
}
```

Then you've to consider that `getParam` is probably a function and no public property / variable, so you had to write it like this:

```
public function myFunction ($product){
    if (is_object($product)) {
        echo $product->getParam();
    } else {
        # catch the error / fault
    }
}
```

Additionally the function `getParam` probably needs a parameter to decide what to return, then the function is looking like this:

```
public function myFunction ($product){
    if (is_object($product)) {
        echo $product->getParam($param);
    } else {
        # catch the error / fault
    }
}
```

Now your problem is, that the new variable `param` is not defined (at least not in local context) and you had to enter an object-property instead (with $this->param) or define `$param` locally like this:

```
public function myFunction ($product){
    if (is_object($product)) {
        $param = 'color';
        echo $product->getParam($param);
    } else {
        # catch the error / fault
    }
}
```

One alternative is that instead of `getParam()` another getter is used which is returning a scalar (string-value or number) i.e. like `getColor()` and you don't need a `param` to call it:

```
public function myFunction ($product){
    if (is_object($product)) {
        echo $product->getColor();
    } else {
        # catch the error / fault
    }
}
```

So all in all you made nearly everything wrong what you could have done wrong. But I think it's a nice walk-through, to show the different details.

Comment: "nearly everything wrong what you could have done wrong" Lol, that's a bit harsh. He was just missing the parenthesis. In a getter you usually don't use parameters, and there's better ways of dealing with types than what you propose.

Comment: @Stratadox If faults are made for learning, then in the end it's no fault, isn't it?

Comment: @Stratadox you mentioned type-hinting that's not bad, but then he's to catch an error somewhere else. He also could check with `if ($product instanceof Product) { ... }`. So there is still much space for improvements, perhaps also namespaces. But it's his very beginning and we never saw much code in the question.

Comment: "If faults are made for learning" When they are learned from, they can provide value in that manner, yes. I'm just not sure these were faults.

Comment: "then he's to catch an error somewhere else" Using a different value from the type hint is a programming error: not something you want to catch, but something you want to solve by changing the code so that the right input is given.

Comment: Imagine you've a banking application, want to transfer something and get an error-message shown. Wouldn't it be nicer if you get at least some info shown how to inform the programming-team?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180165/discussion-between-stratadox-and-david).